# How to disable vim's indentation after "case"?

Tags: vim, editor, text-editor

I want my code indent like this:

```
switch (msg)
{
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
}
```

But Vim always indent code like this:

```
switch (msg)
{
    case WM_CREATE:
        {
            DoSomething();
        }
}
```

My vimrc file is:

```
set autoindent
filetype plugin indent on
```

What's more, I hava tried:

```
set cindent 
set smartindent 
set cinoption=l1
```

But they all do not work, 
I really do not know how to fix it, 
Can you help me?

BYW: I am not English native speaker, please forgive me if there are any errors about grammar.

Comment: Side note: You don't need `{}` with `case` in any of the languages that derive their syntax from B (C, C++, C#, Java, JavaScript, ...). So just not using `{}` might do what you want. The only reason for using a block within a `case` is (in a subset of those languages) to create a local scope for variables specific to the case; something which would be better handled by writing a function and calling it.

Comment: This will be handled by the smart indentation plugin for the progarmming language you're using. What language is it?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Your guess is right, I use {} for local variables, why it's better to handle it by writing a function rather than using {}?  It's C language.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder what is smart indentation plugin? set smartindent? I have try it.

Comment: *"why it's better to handle it by writing a function rather than using {}"* Because one of the first rules of effective programming is *keep functions short*. (A rule I have a lot of trouble obeying. :-) ) If you need local variables within a `case`, the `case` is almost certainly too big. Refactor the contents of the `case` into a function and call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `.vimrc` file:

```
set cino==0
```

That sets the indent after `case` to zero. You can find the various options for `cindent` [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/indent.html#cinoptions-values).